# How can I tell if "badblocks" is still working?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, terminal

I started "badblocks" without any options on my 1 TB external harddisk as below:

```
>> sudo badblocks /dev/sdb
```

Its been running for the past three days, and all what I can see is a long column of numbers on my terminal (As below):

```
...
457970423
458749684
458749685
458749686
458749687
495098888
495098889
495098890
495098891
```

Now it's been stuck (no change) on 495098891 (which may be a  bad sector or something...)
My question is, How can I tell if it is still working ? or maybe it's stuck somewhere...
and is it safe to stop it (Ctrl-C) ??? or it might damage my external ???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using iotop which shows a nice detailed table, showing that there is read activity on the disk... therefore, I am sure the application is not stuck, and I will wait longer.

```
>> sudo iotop
```